# For a non-empty subset $S$ and a point $x$ in a connected metric space $(X,d)$, let $d(x,S)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in{S}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

For a non-empty subset $S$ and a point $x$ in a connected metric space $(X,d)$, let $d(x,S)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in{S}\}$. Which of the following statements is/are correct?

A. If $S$ is closed and $d(x,S)>0$ then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$

B. If $S$ is open  and $d(x,S)>0$ then $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$

C. If $S$ is closed and $d(x,S)>0$ then $S$ does not contain $x$

D. Is $S$ is open and $d(x,S)=0$ then $x\in{S}$

**My attempt**: For (D). is wrong because is $S=(0,1)$ and $x=1$, $d(x,s)=0$ but $x\notin{S}$

Answer (score 1):

Note $d(x,S) = d(x, \textrm{cl}(S))$ and $d(x,S) = 0$ iff $x \in \textrm{cl}(S)$. 
I'll prove the second claim and leave the first one to you.

$x \in \textrm{cl}(S)$ iff there exists $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset S$ such that $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$. Then, $d(x,x_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. BUt then the distance from $x$ to $S$ must tend to $0$. Hence $x \in \textrm{cl}(S)$ iff $d(x,S) = 0$.

For A, this shows if $d(x,S) > 0$ and $S$ is closed then $x \not \in \textrm{cl}(S) = S$. I hope you can attempt the rest of them from here.

Comment: @ Giant ...sorry i am not understand can you explain me briefly

Comment: Ok, I will edit my post.

Comment: @Giant...Ok thanks for your time ..i am waiting

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First of all note that a closed set contains its all limit points.

A-(T) If $S$ is closed and suppose $x$ is limit point then $d(x,S)=0$ (see above hint). Contradiction.

B-(T) What is distance of $0$ from the open set $(0,1)$?

C-(T) Obvious. If you got my logic written above.

D-(F) You know the reason.

Thanks. I hope this helps.